# Synchronizing UIView animations

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, core-animation

Hi in response to touch events, my application does view animation. If the user is really fast and does another touch even while the current animation is happening then everything gets messed up.

Is there a standard way to handle this problem provided by the framework? Or am I doing the animation in a wrong way?

Currently it is checking a flag (animationInProgress) to handle this but I wanted to know if that is what we have to resort to for this?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    NSMutableArray *c = (NSMutableArray*)context;
    UINavigationController *nc = [c objectAtIndex:0];
    [nc.view removeFromSuperview];
    animationInProgress = NO;
}

- (void)transitionViews:(BOOL)topToBottom {
    if (animationInProgress) {
        return;
    }
    animationInProgress = YES;
    NSMutableArray *context = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"myanim" context:context];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.7f];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];

    UIViewController *from;
    UIViewController *to;
    if (navController3.view.superview == nil ) {
        from = navController2;
        to = navController3;
    } else {
        from = navController3;
        to = navController2;
    }

    int height;
    if (topToBottom) { 
        height = -1 * from.view.bounds.size.height;
    } else {
        height = from.view.bounds.size.height;
    }

    CGAffineTransform transform = from.view.transform;

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    to.view.bounds = from.view.layer.bounds;
    to.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, height);
    [window addSubview:to.view];

    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
    from.view.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(from.view.transform, 0, -1 * height);
    to.view.transform = transform;

    [context addObject:from];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default behavior of the frameworks is, as you noticed, to allow anything to happen simultaneously if you want it to.

Using a flag like you're doing is perfectly reasonable if your goal is to block a specific animation from happening if it's already running.

If you want to go "up a level" conceptually and stop any touch events from entering your application at all during the animation, you can use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

paired with a:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

Comment: If you stop any touch events from entering your application during animation using begin/endIgnoringInteractionEvents, what happens with the touch events that might arrive while in this block? Will they be cached and presented to the app once endIgnoringInteractionEvents is called or does it throws away all touches (as the name suggests)?

Comment: @vance: They will be thrown away, as the name suggests.